# Pascal to C# Conversion error

Tags: c#

I have converted game from pascal to C# but when I start program and type in target value and values for finding that value program gives me error: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Pascal source: http://pastebin.com/AR390Am2
C# Source: http://pastebin.com/n0Fr2zYB

[image]

Comment: Index was outside the bounds of the array http://imageshack.com/a/img922/1971/dTEzm7.png

Comment: on what line you get that error? Basically the issue is that arrays are from `0`..`len-1` and I can see you iterate from `1` to `len`.

Comment: Indeed, `new bool[6]` is not a translation of `array[1..6] of boolean`, it's a translation of `array[0..5] of boolean`. You could make that change in the Pascal code and adapt the rest of the code to match, and then make those same changes in the C# code, if that helps get a clearer picture on things.

Comment: ....you're trying to access index 6 in an array with the highest index value at 5

Comment: You should write your error message here. Not every one want to open external links as we cannot be sure that it is not spam.

Comment: To make the conversion easier, you might create your won C# class `PascalArray` if you have a lot of code to convert.

Comment: When I changed this loop for (prog.u = 1; prog.u < 6; prog.u++) to for (prog.u = 0; prog.u < 5; prog.u++) I get this error: Attempted to divide by zero.

Comment: When I changed all loops to start from 0 to n-1,those that start with other number than 0 I set to start from value reduced by 1 to n-1  I still get error: Index was outside the bounds of the array

Answer (score 2):

The root of the problem is, that in Pascal you could define the range of an array (in this case 1-6), in c# it starts always from index 0 (0-5).

If you try to port code from Pascal to C#, you have to check all places, where array indices are used.

Example:

for (... ; i

Also be careful with ranges of integer types. (int, int64)

Comment: I changed this loop for (prog.u = 1; prog.u < 6; prog.u++) to for (prog.u = 0; prog.u < 5; prog.u++) now I have this error: http://imageshack.com/a/img923/8677/WIBoHG.png

Comment: I am afraid that is the problem I mentioned above "check all places, where array indices are used".  There error means, the variable niz[j] is 0 and you cannot divide by 0. But the root cause will be, the variable is not filled before because of a wrong index.

Answer (score 0):

You declare

```
bool[] uzet = new bool[6];
```

And try to access it at index `6` which is why you get the error.

Declaring `new bool[6]` initialize an array of length 6 where available indexes are 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Change your condition to:

```
if (i < 6)
    uzet[i] = true;
```

On line 84

Comment: When I change to if( i <6) I get error: http://imageshack.com/a/img922/820/bFGIXp.png